# How to insert function in PDF document?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Is anyone familiar with plugging a function into a PDF document (specifically, the "insert custom code" feature in Adobe Acrobat Pro)? I know it's possible to initiate a function on an event...but I'm not sure what event would best handle this. I'd assume a button press. Also, does anyone know which language is compatible with PDFs? Is Javascript the only one? I don't imagine a server-side code (like PHP or Ruby) would work. Or the use of a framework like JQuery. Maybe it's only ActionScript or some strict language like C#. I dunno :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this page on the Adobe Acrobat developer site:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/overview.html#JavaScript

This explains that the language you're referring to is JavaScript with a number of additional objects related to Acrobat itself exposed.

So if you want to add functionality inside a PDF file (commonly either as the result of a button press indeed, but you can also do field validation, things at document open etc...) it will have to be JavaScript. Read this page to get all details about JavaScript (including the reference):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

Comment: Great. Thank you. It would have been too easy for me to just look on the Adobe site for tips :P Haha Thanks though.